# Where is the Certificate chain file on Mac? (MAMP Pro 5.0.1)

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I am setting up SSL for testing in MAMP Pro 5.0.1, and following instruction [here](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Settings/Hosts/SSL/), and have generated dummy certs.

The instruction say to "Point to your chain file or Alias", but there is no mention of where to find the "chain file or Alias". Spotlight can't find them either. Where is the chain file stored?

Comment: It is a shame no one has answered this.